# Is there a way to get notified when a child is added/removed from a WPF Panel?

Tags: wpf

I can't find the event that would get fired when a child is added or removed from a WPF panel.  Does such an event exist and I am just missing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you could wrap your panel in a UserControl (perhaps called ObservablePanel?), which has an AddChild method that fires an event after adding the item to the panel.

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't find an event, but you might try the [`Panel.OnVisualChildrenChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.onvisualchildrenchanged(VS.85).aspx) method.

Comment: This is the easiest way to get add/remove notifications if you are writing a custom panel, as the method can just be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to override Panel.CreateUIElementCollection(...), so it returns custom type derived from UIElementCollection. In UIElementCollection you can override Add, Remove, etc.

```
public class CustomPanel: Panel
{
    protected override UIElementCollection CreateUIElementCollection(FrameworkElement logicalParent)
    {
        ObservableUIElementCollection uiECollection = new ObservableUIElementCollection(this, logicalParent);
        uiECollection.RaiseAddUIElement += OnUIElementAdd;


        return uiECollection;
    }
}

public class ObservableUIElementCollection : UIElementCollection
{
    public ObservableUIElementCollection(UIElement visualParent, FrameworkElement logicalParent)
        : base(visualParent, logicalParent)
    {

    }

    public event EventHandler<UIElement> RaiseAddUIElement;

    public override int Add(UIElement element)
    {
        OnRiseAddUIElementEvent(element);
        return base.Add(element);
    }

    protected virtual void OnRiseAddUIElementEvent(UIElement e)
    {
        // copy to avoid race condition
        EventHandler<UIElement> handler = RaiseAddUIElement;

        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, e);
    }


}
```